# Trying To Centre Search Box With Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to properly centre an autofill search box with its dropdown suggestion list.

Because the drop down suggestion list was pushing content down I had to make it position:absolute. Because I made it position:absolute centering that element was possible but I had to use a different way then how I centered the search box. As a result as I change the size of the screen the two centerings don't move in line with each other

So my problem is that the search box (id #keyword)and search button (id #myBtn) are set at width 60% and 10% respectively and sit next to each other. The drop down box (id #results) is meant to centre and sit under the total length of both of them. I have had to set it at 60% width. So while it does centre I don't think I am doing this right as when I responsively move the screen size the centerings do not move together.

Here's the relevant cut of the code

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="jumbo" class="jumbotron">
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" id="keyword">
        <input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Go">
        <div id="results">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="trainstation" style="background-color:blue;width:100%;margin:auto;height:100px;"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

CSS

#keyword {
    width:60%;
    height:50px;
    margin:auto;
    font-size:2vw;
}
#myBtn {
    width:10%;
    height:50px;
    margin:auto;
    font-size:2vw;
    position:relative;
    left:-0.5%;
    border:2px solid #207cca;
    background-color:#207cca;
    color:#fafafa;
}
#myBtn:hover {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color:#207cca;
}
#results {
    width:60%;
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    display:none;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:10000;
}
```

Comment: try making `#jumbo` `position:relative;`

Comment: when setting an offset of an element that is set to `position:absolute `, always remember that such elements distance is measure from the nearest parent that is `position: relative`, or to the `body`.

Comment: Thanks r3wt. That gives me a good understanding now why that worked